# Is returning pointer to struct-pointer created inside a function safe?

Tags: c, matrix

Is it a safe practice to do this? Will the local variable `mat` get destroyed after the `multiply()` function is complete? Will this effect `mat4` later in the `main()` program?

In matrix.h

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    double **entries;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} Matrix;
```

In matrix.c

```
int check_dimensions_for_multiplication(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2)
{
    if (m1->cols == m2->rows)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

Matrix *matrix_create(int rows, int cols)
{
    Matrix *matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    matrix->rows = rows;
    matrix->cols = cols;
    matrix->entries = malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix->entries[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));
    }
    return matrix;
}

Matrix *multiply(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2)
{
    if (check_dimensions_for_multiplication(m1, m2))
    {
        Matrix *mat = matrix_create(m1->rows, m2->cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2->cols; j++)
            {
                mat->entries[i][j] = m1->entries[i][j] * m2->entries[i][j];
            }
        }
        return mat;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Dimension mismatch multiply: %dx%d %dx%d\n", m1->rows, m1->cols, m2->rows, m2->cols);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

In `main.c`:

```
Matrix *mat4 = multiply(mat2, mat1);
```

Comment: Memory obtained with `malloc` can be used until it is `free`d (or until the end of program execution). The local pointer variable will be destroyed, but you returned its value.

Comment: Please note that the result of the multiplication should have `m1->rows` rows and `m2->cols` columns and the posted algorithm is not what a matrix multiplication should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, variables allocated in the heap via `malloc` should not be destroyed after the function terminates.

```
int * someInteger = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This code will allocate some memory (probably 4 bytes) at a location called the heap, a space given to your program by the Operating System. Memory allocated in the Heap is a permanent piece of memory that propagates throughout the lifetime of your program unless you `free` that particular pointer.

Only assigned local variables are destroyed since they are stored on the stack.

You can check this website if you want more information on local variables and stack

[http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Matthew.James/engn3213-2002/notes/upnode25.html#:~:text=The%20stack%20is%20used%20for,variables%20in%20the%20stack%20frame](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7EMatthew.James/engn3213-2002/notes/upnode25.html#:%7E:text=The%20stack%20is%20used%20for,variables%20in%20the%20stack%20frame).